# How to mock arbitrary behavior with Rhino Mocks?

Tags: unit-testing, .net-2.0, c#-2.0, rhino-mocks-3.5, arrange-act-assert

I'm trying to mock a data layer method. The method takes a string and two lists as arguments, and the method populates those lists from the results of a stored proc. Also, I'm still on C# 2.0 with VS2005, and I'm using Rhino Mocks 3.5 for .NET 2.0. If possible, it would be nice to use the AAA format.

So yeah, all I want to do is mock an interface method that will add a couple of fake objects to the argument lists and return. Unfortunately, after reading the Rhino Mocks documentation, I have little to no idea how to do this. Rhino is a unintelligible puzzle box to me and I'm powerless to do anything without examples; examples that I can't find.

Anyone have any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the AAA syntax with .NET 2.0, it's just a little bit more typing.  See [Using the AAA syntax in C# 2.0](http://ayende.com/Wiki/Rhino+Mocks+3.5.ashx#UsingtheAAAsyntaxinCCA)

Comment: yeah, C#2.0 means a lot of delegate keywords, and even more ridiculous delegate type definition, but it does work. On a different note, interestingly, even though I'm using VS2005 I still see the extension method icon next to method names in intellisense!